# How to figure out why object is not rendered after removing/add materials in Python API?

Tags: python, rendering

How to figure what is wrong here? Parts of planes are rendered, but the boat does not render at all.

This seems to happen when I join objects, remove materials, then add a new material manually:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
bpy.ops.object.join()
obj = bpy.context.object
obj.data.materials.clear()
```

[image: Two planes and a boat]

What is interesting, removing materials by hand doesn't lead to the same issue:
[image: By hand]
[image: In python]

Comment: Looks like the problem is `obj.data.materials.clear()`. I used `while obj.data.materials: bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()` and it worked fine.